# Why the layout of holding of structure in memory doesnt matter for serialization/deserialization functions in C programming

Tags: c, linux

I am new at C programming. I wanted to comprehend structure of DB to get new experience in programming and CS. So I started writing and right now I am at third section `https://cstack.github.io/db_tutorial/parts/part3.html`

Question: so there is snippet of code where OFFSET of field of structure are written

```
typedef struct {
    
    uint32_t id;
    char username[32];
    char email[255];

} Row;

#define size_of_attribute(Struct, Attribute) sizeof(((Struct*)0)->Attribute)

const uint32_t ID_SIZE = size_of_attribute(Row, id);
const uint32_t USERNAME_SIZE = size_of_attribute(Row, username);
const uint32_t EMAIL_SIZE = size_of_attribute(Row, email);
const uint32_t ID_OFFSET = 0;
const uint32_t USERNAME_OFFSET = ID_OFFSET + ID_SIZE;
const uint32_t EMAIL_OFFSET = USERNAME_OFFSET + USERNAME_SIZE;
const uint32_t ROW_SIZE = ID_SIZE + USERNAME_SIZE + EMAIL_SIZE;
```

and after that the author wrote serialization function

```
void serialize_row(Row *source, void *destination){

    memcpy(destination + ID_OFFSET , &(source->id) , ID_SIZE );
    memcpy(destination + USERNAME_OFFSET, &(source->username),USERNAME_SIZE);
    memcpy(destination + EMAIL_OFFSET, &(source->email),EMAIL_SIZE);

    return;
}
```

But I know that structure can be saved in the RAM **not consecutively**,
because compiler seeks to hold data in the size of power of 2(not only compiler). Anyways, for first element it will work because first element are required to be placed at once,but subsequent fields can be not after first field at once(there can be free spaces). It means that just **USERNAME_OFFSET** or **EMAIL_OFFSET** won't work.

Please explain to me that.

I am using Manjaro linux(OS)

gcc(compiler)

gdb(debugger)

Comment: Where's the definition of `u`?

Comment: Since you tagged as C++, the `typedef` is not necessary when declaring variables or parameters.

Comment: The serialized layout of data doesn't need to match the in-memory representation.  Alignment and padding don't do anything for you in a file, so there's no need to write them to your serialized representation.

Comment: Sorry,it was error of copy/paste of code. It is just ```uint32_t```

Comment: Since you tagged as C++, you should be using the `g++` compiler.

Comment: You want: `const uint32_t EMAIL_OFFSET = USERNAME_OFFSET + USERNAME_SIZE;` which _is_ what the link shows.

Comment: I tagged it as c++ and c,because I thought it could be useful for c++ programmer too

Comment: yeah, I've edited all my code

Comment: Addition of `void*` + `some integer value` is undefined, IIRC.

Comment: Whoever wrote this code was confused. Correct code should be taking the address of members or use `offsetof`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, exactly, you are right, and your suspicions are right. There is no guarantee that struct members are consecutive, there may be padding between struct members and the code does not handle that.

Specially for that reason, there exists `offsetof` macro https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/offsetof .

Also, initializing a `const` with a value of another `const` is not part of C language, and is supported as an extension. In C, you have to repeat it (or use macros, as they expand).

Also, you should prefer to use `size_t`, not `uint32_t`, to represent sizes and indexes.

```
const size_t ID_OFFSET = offsetof(Row, id);
const size_t USERNAME_OFFSET = offsetof(Row, username);
const size_t EMAIL_OFFSET = offsetof(Row, email);
const size_t ROW_SIZE = sizeof(Row);
```

> compiler seeks to hold data in the size of power of 2(not only compiler)

Hm, it's not always size of 2, it's aligned to `alignof(type)`, which varies with type. So `char` does not need any adjustment, it can be anywhere, but `long` is usually aligned to 4 bytes. You may want to read http://www.catb.org/esr/structure-packing/ .

Comment: Hi,thanks. I know that ```const``` in C is ```read-only```, it is not constant. I will bear it in mind **size_t instead of uint32_t**. But right now I would like to follow this blog completely, because it is my first more or less serious project in programming especially on C

Answer (score 1):

In order to serialize/deserialize, all you need to ensure is that there is sufficient space (so data elements aren't over written by each other ) and have the serialize() and deserialize() functions agree on the format.
For your example, it could have been:

```
size_t serialize_row(Row *source, void *dest) {
    return sprintf(dest, "(%s,%d,%s)", source->email, source->id, source->username);
}

int deserialize_row(void *source, Row *dest) {
    int n;  
    n = sscanf(dest, "(%s,%d,%s)", source->email, &source->id, source->username);
    return n == 3;
}
```

The order doesn't matter, the external form has no bearing on the internal form, and all that is important is managing the buffer & io-sizes.   Note, btw, that if `source->email` or `source->name` contained a `)`, it could make this fail, so a more robust example is called for.

Answer (score 0):

Because when you do serialization function, it doesn't matter how will you save it in the file or in the space of HEAP memory. You use as source exact address of each field and just use its size as amount of bytes. When you do deserialization function, it doesn't matter again because you just put all data consecutively and by hand and compiler(if it is necessary) will add padding to the end of the structure.

Comment: I understand why it doesn't matter how it is stored in RAM, and replied to my own question. I think it can be useful for begginers who write their own **serialization/deserialization** functions using ```struct``` in C why it doesn't matter how it is hold in memory.